# Display Error Message in client ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, vue.js, axios

Im tryin to show a message y the user introduce a wrong password.
In server shows the correcte message, but in client browser show a Bad Request message.
this is the code in controller

```
throw new Exception ("Incorrect");
```

Vue template

```
axios.post(window.url + 'usuarios/LogIn', this.data).then((response) => {
                        console.log('Correct')
                    }).catch((error) => {
                        // Error                            
                        if (error.response) {
                            console.log(error.response.data);
                            this.error = error.response.data;
                        } else if (error.request) {
                            console.log(error.request);
                            this.error = error.request;
                        } else {
                            console.log('Error', error.message);
                            this.error = error.mes;
                        }
```

Comment: server exceptions are not passed to the response. you need to construct a response manually

Comment: can you explain how do that please?

Comment: assuming you are using web API then `return BadRequest("Incorrect")`